# d3 update tree layout with dynamic data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

What's the easiest way to update model with d3 tree layout.

here's the example
http://jsfiddle.net/mnk/vfro9tkz/

```
var data = {
  name: 'Music',
  children: [{
    name: 'Rock',
    children: [{
      name: 'Two'
    }, {
      name: 'Three',
      children: [{
        name: 'A'
      }, {
        name: 'Bonjourallo'
      }, {
        name: 'Coco coco coco coco'
      }]
    }, {
      name: 'Four'
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Rap',
    children: [{
      name: 'Hip-Hop/Rap'
    }]
  }]
};
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg');

svg.attr('width', 700)
  .attr('height', 400);

var tree = d3.layout.tree().size([600, 300]);

function update(model) {

  var nodes = tree.nodes(model);
  var links = tree.links(nodes);

  nodes.forEach(function(d, i) {
    d.index = d.parent ? d.parent.children.indexOf(d) : 0;
    d.width = getNameLength(d.name);

    if (!hasNephewOrChildren(d)) {
      d.x = getHorizontalPosition(d)
      d.y = (d.parent ? d.parent.y : 0) + 40;
      d.mode = 'horizontal';
    } else {
      d.x = d.depth * 60;
      d.y = getVerticalPosition(d);
      d.mode = 'vertical';
    }
  });

  var node = svg.selectAll('.node')
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append('g').attr('class', 'node')
    .attr('opacity', 1)
    .attr('visibility', function(d) {
      return d.depth ? 'visible' : 'hidden'
    })
    .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
      return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')'
    });


  var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return d.y;
    })
    .interpolate("linear");

  var paths = svg.selectAll('g.node').append("path")
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      return lineFunction(generatePath(d));
    })
    .attr("stroke", "#aaa")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1)
    .attr("fill", "none");

  function generatePath(d) {
    var points = [];

    if (d.depth > 1) {
      if (d.mode === 'horizontal') {
        points.push({
          x: d.parent.x - d.x + d.parent.width,
          y: -25
        });
        points.push({
          x: d.width / 2,
          y: -25
        });
        points.push({
          x: d.width / 2,
          y: 0
        });
      } else {
        points.push({
          x: d.parent.x - d.x + d.parent.width / 2,
          y: d.parent.y - d.y + 30
        });
        points.push({
          x: d.parent.x - d.x + d.parent.width / 2,
          y: 15
        });
        points.push({
          x: d.parent.x - d.x + d.parent.width / 2 + 15,
          y: 15
        });
      }
    }
    return points;
  }

  node.append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'rect')
    .attr('width', function(d, i) {
      return d.width
    })
    .attr('height', 30)
    .attr('rx', 15)

  node.append('text')
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name
    })
    .attr('x', 10)
    .attr('y', 20);

  var close = node.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'remove-icon-group')
    .on('click', function(d) {
      console.log('todo remove d and all childrens.');
      // update(model);
    })
    .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
      return 'translate(' + (d.width - 15) + ',15)'
    });

  close.append('circle')
    .attr('class', 'remove-icon')
    .attr('r', 10)

  close.append('line')
    .attr('x1', -4)
    .attr('x2', 4)
    .attr('y1', -4)
    .attr('y2', 4)
    .attr('stroke', '#a0a0a0')
    .attr('stroke-width', 1);


  close.append('line')
    .attr('x1', 4)
    .attr('x2', -4)
    .attr('y1', -4)
    .attr('y2', 4)
    .attr('stroke', '#a0a0a0')
    .attr('stroke-width', 1);
}

update(data);

function getLastDescendant(d) {
  if (d.children && d.children.length) {
    return getLastDescendant(d.children[d.children.length - 1]);
  }

  return d;
}

function hasNephewOrChildren(d) {
  var siblings = d.parent ? d.parent.children : [d];
  var hasChildren = false;

  siblings.forEach(function(sibling) {
    if (sibling.children && sibling.children.length) {
      hasChildren = true;
    }
  });

  return hasChildren;
}

function getHorizontalPosition(d) {
  if (d.index === 0) {
    return d.parent ? d.parent.x + 60 : 0;
  }

  var prevSibling = d.parent.children[d.index - 1];

  return prevSibling.x + prevSibling.width + 10;
}

function getVerticalPosition(d) {
  var prevY = (d.parent ? d.parent.y : -40);

  if (d.index) {
    var prevSibling = d.parent.children[d.index - 1];
    var lastDescendant = getLastDescendant(prevSibling);
    prevY = lastDescendant.y;
  }

  return prevY + 40;
}

function getNameLength(str) {
  var length = str.length * 8;
  return length < 60 ? 60 + 30 : length + 30;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're very close. You already have all the drawing code extracted to `update`, and there's a place where you've commented out that you need to call it again. You need to figure out how to modify the model in response to user clicks, and then call `update` with the new model.

The thing you'll encounter is that when you call `update` again, some DOM nodes will already be onscreen. That is, the enter selection will be empty, but the update selection will not be. The simplest, and ugliest, way to handle this is to remove and re-add all the nodes:

```
svg.selectAll('.node').remove();
svg.selectAll('.node')
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("g") // and so on
```

The better way to do it is explained in the [General Update Pattern](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218) (be sure to see all three). You should also read the last paragraph of the [.enter() docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#enter).